# How to check if form is dirty for dynamically added field in fieldset ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I tried:

```
form.isDirty(); // return true or false for static form field
```

But when I'm add field dynamically in fieldset that method not work.
Also I tried update layout `window.updateLayout()` after add field but it not helped.
Who know how resolve this problem?

Comment: Plz add some codes how you have added the field dynamically in form..

Answer (score 0):

To check if all the fields in a form are valid, you need to use the method [isValid](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-isValid)

The fields in a form need a name property to be validated.